# Azure Universal Package Versioning

Tags: azure, devops

We're building out binaries and publishing them over in an Artifact feed in Azure Devops. Our current versioning scheme is using SemVer2.0 with the three part version (x.x.x), we wanted to place some tag on versions (e.g. 1.0.0-beta) but when downloading the universal packages using a wildcard version ( * ) we get an error saying the version doesn't exist.

Is placing version suffixes supported in Azure DevOps universal package? Or is there a way to tag a certain version as a beta release or alpha release.

Answer (score 1):

You can use views for exactly this purpose, if my understanding is correct.

By default, your feed will have 3 views: `@local`, `@prerelease` and `@release`. You can rename the views, change the default view and add additional views in feed settings (the cog icon on the right) - Views

[image: Azure Devops feed settings]

You can then promote your packages to the appropriate view and use that information to trigger a release or to download the specific version that was promoted (at least in a pipeline you can use this as a 'filter' in the Download package task). The below example is of a UP as a release pipeline trigger:

[image: Azure Devops release pipeline with UP trigger]

In this example I'm actually trying to trigger the same pipeline in 2 different cases (promotion of the package to either `@prerelease` or to `@release` should both trigger the pipeline, but the subsequent logic in the pipeline should be different). I'm still not sure this is actually possible, which was the initial reason why I was reading your question. I'll probably create a separate question for that specific topic.